# How can I get FileZilla to ignore folder or files (like .svn or CVS)?

Tags: ftp, filezilla, ignore

How can I get FileZille to ignore folders or files? I don't want to upload my version-control info to my web-server!

(question implied in [a comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1241/must-have-windows-software/3870#3870) to another answer).

Comment: Surely the best way in this case would be to do a **svn/cvs export** of your source before uploading it? That way you are sure not to upload some random svn/cvs file

Comment: Perhaps. But there are use cases beyond the two examples above.

Comment: If you need to upload code regularly to keep backups on a client site (and they don't want to pay for something like beanstalkapp) then this filter is very important

Answer (score 77, accepted):

In FileZilla 3+ , click on the "filter directory listings"* button on the task-bar for a listing of existing filters to apply, edit, or add your a custom filter.

* it's the right-most button (with three arrows) in the middle-row in [image: filter button, among others]
(image from http://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Using )

[Detailed info on FileZilla filters](http://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Filename_Filters)

Comment: In the version of FileZilla I'm using (3.39.0), the icon is gone but I'm able to handle filtering from the "View" menu under "Directory listing filters..." (shortcut key: Ctrl + I).

Answer (score 29):

Click on View -> Filename filters
(Filezilla 3.3)

Answer (score 15):

For Filezilla 3.14 this option is under: **View -> Filename filters...**

Here is the dialog (with `GIT`, `bower_components` and `node_modules` custom rules):

[image]

As you can see SVN exclusion is now available by default. GIT and others has to be added manually with **Edit filter rules...** button.

Here is how rules editor looks (with GIT rule as an example):

[image]

Answer (score 6):

#### Complete Solution.

Here is all you need to Do.

**Shortcut** :: Command + I (Mac)
OR
Open FileZilla > View > Filename Filters

[image: View Filters Image]

Then Click Edit Filter Rule on this screen bottom left corner button.

[image: Edit Filter Rule]

As you can see in this image, you can now

- Click on the + button
- Create a new row
- Add Change First Dropdown value to *path*
- Change Second Dropdown value to *contains*
- in the third text box type .git

**This is how now when you will simply click on your repo folder and want to upload all the files, .git folder will not be uploaded.**

> Voila !! Similary you can do the same for your node_modules folder or other folders as well.
>
> The best practice is to just create a distribution folder which must contain all the serving files for the client and just hit upload for that distribution folder.

---

> Note :: I am sorry folks i do not have enough reputation to embed images here, So Please do a right click on the images and open them in a separate page instead for now. I will update this once i earn that much reputation

Answer (score 2):

On Filezilla (3.7), toggle:

> Server -> Force showing hidden files

Answer (score 1):

Filezilla Filters:

[image]

For example you want to exclude Files and Folders that begin with "." 
i.e.

```
.config
.pathexclude
```

etc

Then in Filezilla:

- select "View > Filename filters...".
- "Edit filter rules..."
- Filename Filters
- Filter only
- .files
- .folders
- begins with : matches if the file/directory name begins with the specified literal string.