# Make Filezilla work with .gitignore files

Tags: git, filezilla, ignore

Is there a way to make Filezilla read the settings i added to .gitignore file and then do the same? (ignore the files specified in the gitignore file)

Comment: Like this? http://superuser.com/questions/13733/how-can-i-get-filezilla-to-ignore-folder-or-files-like-svn-or-cvs

Comment: yes but i dont want to redo it, i want it to read the .gitignore files and understand what the file is saying

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Filezilla does not read the contents of files, nor does it act upon them.
But have no fear, there are still a couple of things you can do:

1. Add FileZilla directory file name filters that will mimic your ignored files
2. FileZilla is an open source product. You can add a feature that will read the .gitignore file and act upon it. Don't forget to share the code with the rest of us when you're done! :)